# Do I need to type the controller in the url every time?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new at CodeIgniter and I'm exploring it's functionalities.

Do I need to type the controller everytime I access the link?

or is there a way that the controller can be called by default even by just typing the domain name or just "localhost:8080"?

I just want to be able to type just www.domainName.com or just localhost:8080 and load my main page.

Comment: `or is there a way that the controller can be called` - probably several, look into setting the default controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set default controller in your config...

Edit /application/config/routes.php

```
<?php

$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';

...
```

Comment: wow Thanks That help. One last question though. is this advisable or will this cause some issues in some cases?